# How to use more than 2 words in containstable

Tags: sql-server

I'm searching for more informations about the containstable to solve my problem

I visited the Microsoft's url

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189760.aspx

And I saw this example

```
CREATE TABLE Flags (Country nvarchar(30) NOT NULL, FlagColors varchar(200));  
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX FlagKey ON Flags(Country);  
INSERT Flags VALUES ('France', 'Blue and White and Red');  
INSERT Flags VALUES ('Italy', 'Green and White and Red');  
INSERT Flags VALUES ('Tanzania', 'Green and Yellow and Black and Yellow and Blue');  
SELECT * FROM Flags;  
GO  

CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG TestFTCat;  
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON Flags(FlagColors) KEY INDEX FlagKey ON TestFTCat;  
GO   

SELECT * FROM Flags;  
SELECT * FROM CONTAINSTABLE (Flags, FlagColors, 'Green') ORDER BY RANK DESC;  
SELECT * FROM CONTAINSTABLE (Flags, FlagColors, 'Green or Black') ORDER BY RANK DESC;
```

This is what I need. But I need to know if the text to be searched has more than two words, how the query will actually be?

I don't know if these examples below are right

```
SELECT * FROM CONTAINSTABLE (Flags, FlagColors, 'Green OR Black OR Yellow')

SELECT * FROM CONTAINSTABLE (Flags, FlagColors, 'Green AND Black AND Yellow')
```

How it will be with more than two terms?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM CONTAINSTABLE (Flags, FlagColors, '"Green AND Black AND Yellow"')
```

I think this may help you...

Comment: Did you enable full text search in your sql server.?

Comment: I don't know Ganesan. Where Can I do this?

Comment: Is it showing any error or warning while you run the query?